# Issue with nested ajax call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a situation where I make an ajax call, on returning from which (successfully), I make an another ajax call with the returned data and submit the page. The pseudo code looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'first_page.jsp',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {...}
}).done(function(response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '2nd_page.jsp',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {...}
    });
    thisPage.submit();
});
```

The inner ajax call is not executed if I do not comment out the 'submit' line. I do not understand the behaviour. Can someone please help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: If `.submit()` refreshes the page, then your second AJAX is unlikely to execute. You may try to execute the submit on the `.done()` of the second AJAX instead.

Comment: More than likely you want to avoid old school form submission. `$(formElement).submit(function(eventObj){ /* do all submission type stuff here */ eventObj.preventDefault(); });`

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute submit on second `ajax` sucess.

For example

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {

            },
            success: function (data) {
    $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {

            },
            success: function (data) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     $("input[type='submit']").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
              url:'abcd.php',
              method:'post',
              type:'json',
              async:false,
              success:function(response){
              $.ajax({
              url:'abcde.php',
              method:'post',
              type:'json',
              data:{res:response},
              success:function(response){
              console.log(response);
              }
              });
              $("form").submit();   
              }

         });
         });
```

Try this one.Its working correctly.

Comment: This example is working correctly. You said your inner ajax is not executed without commenting "thisPage.submit();" statement. But this one is correctly  executed with this "$("form").submit();" statment.